# How to make this code more efficient Python/Pyspark Looping

Tags: python, pyspark

Problem to Solve: Using a sorted list of keys, perform the following evaluation starting with the minimum key value and progressing incrementally through the key list.

- Set the initial `Threshold` to the minimum Key value.
- Set the initial `UniqueID` to 1.
- If the `Key` value is less than or equal to the `Threshold`, then insert the existing `Threshold` and `UniqueID` into the proper columns in the row.
- If the `Key` value is greater than the `Threshold`, increment the `Unique`ID by 1 and `Threshold` by 10 and insert those values into the proper columns in the row.
- Use the incremented values in subsequent comparisons and inserts.

Input Data :

| Key |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 10 |
| 15 |

Required Output :

| Key | Threshold | UniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 11 | 2 |
| 10 | 11 | 2 |
| 15 | 21 | 3 |

The below code works but needs to be optimized since I need to run it on a huge data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Key'] = list(range(0, 16, 5))
df['Key'][0] = 1

df["UniqueID"] = None
df["Threshold"] = None

Threshold = int(df.Key.min())+10
GroupID =1

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['Key'])<=Threshold:
      df.loc[index,'UniqueID'] = GroupID
      df.loc[index,'Threshold'] = Threshold
    else:
      df.loc[index,'UniqueID'] = GroupID = GroupID+1
      df.loc[index,'Threshold'] = Threshold = Threshold+10
```

**Solution 2:**

Thought of created the Threshold alone using the below syntax but still it's inefficient

```
i=0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df['Threshold'] = np.where(df['Key']>df['Threshold'],df['Threshold'].shift(1,axis=0).add(10),df['Threshold']
i+=1
print("Working on row",i)
```

**Solution 3:**
Thought of creating a continuous series of Key numbers with a uniqueID incrementing after 10 rows then joining the table with the main table. Again this is a cost-inefficient way.

I would be left joining 5M rows with 50M rows. I woulkd like to try this in Pyspark

(The generated Key data is for example only.)

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: I will post it there.

Comment: You shouldn’t cross post, so choose one.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar:Sure removing this

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: I will stick to this. Have some issue login in the other account